# Copying the data from the old table to the new table with only different new table has sequence

Tags: oracle, sequence

I need to create a new table from old one, need to insert the rows from the old one, only change is the new sequence column needs to be added in the new one. 
Can someone please help me for the same?

```
INSERT INTO dps_session_map (TrackSESSION_SEQ,session_seq, column3)
   SELECT
        A.SEQ_Session.NEXTVAL, sm.session_seq, sm.column3
    FROM 
        dps_session_map  A,

        dps_exec_session_map sm
WHERE   sm.session_seq is not null;
```

Comment: You haven't said what isn't working. What is the error you get?

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Recent versions allow creating a sequence column that gets incremented automatically.  Add a tag with your version like Oracle12c, Oracle11g, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the VALUES keyword and its brackets:

```
--general pattern of inserting from one table to another existing table 
INSERT INTO table(columns)
SELECT columns FROM othertable
```

Column count and type must match (or be implicitly convertible)

If your new table doesn't exist, do:

```
CREATE TABLE x AS
(SELECT columns FROM othertable)
```

Comment: In the new table there is sequence column as well which needs to be added

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying. If your new table had a column that gets values from a sequence or some other default, leave it out of the list of columns inserted

Comment: Let me rephrase the query statement.. I need to take all the columns from the old table and create new table with one more column sequence column

Comment: If the destination table doesn't exist, use create table xyz as (select...)

Comment: The destination table exists .. just insert statement is having problem

Comment: Why do address the sequence as  A.SEQ_Session.NEXTVAL? Reference the sequence by it's schema and name. The sequence doesn't belong to a table.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dps_session_map (TrackSESSION_SEQ,session_seq, column3)
   SELECT
        **SCHEMA.**SEQ_Session.NEXTVAL, sm.session_seq, sm.column3
    FROM 
        dps_session_map  A,
        dps_exec_session_map sm
WHERE   sm.session_seq is not null;
```

Reference the sequence by its name or fully qualified schema.name. Sequences don't belong to table. Are you getting a "ORA-02289: sequence does not exist" error?

Comment: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
02287. 00000 -  "sequence number not allowed here"
*Cause:    The specified sequence number (CURRVAL or NEXTVAL) is inappropriate
           here in the statement.
*Action:   Remove the sequence number.

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned and getting above error

Comment: Is dps_session_map a table or a view?